# postgresql - unnest, for each result

Tags: postgresql, unnest

I would like to create a view and I do some data handling for each result of unnest function.

In my column column2 I have :

1. "12345"
2. "123456"
3. "12345,123456" or more number

I would like to do some *unnest(col2, ',')* and for each result do something like this:

```
if length(col2) = 5 then treatment_1
else if length(col2) = 6 then treatment_2
```

Example in table:

```
col1      col2        
-------------------
D1        12345, 123456
D3        12345
D4        123456
```

Expected Result into a view (with a treatment for each row in a col2) :

```
col1      col2        
-------------------
D1        12345
D1        123456
D3        12345
D4        123456
```

Comment: What data type is col2?

Comment: Col2 is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-matching.html) to split the string into multiple rows:

```
select  t1.col1
,       case 
        when length(split.col2) > 5 then right(split.col2, 3)
        else replace(split.col2, '123', '***')
        end as col2
from    Table1 t1
cross join
         regexp_split_to_table(t1.col2, '\s*,\s*') split(col2)
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/73dc0/11/0)

Comment: Ok, I know how to do that, but how can I apply a treatment for each result ?

Comment: What kind of treatment?  You can use `case`, like `when len(col2) > 5 then ... else ... end`. But that can only transform a value, not split it into multiple rows

Comment: I would like to do both. First split, and do some treatment on each value (I want to apply a right function, and a replace).

Comment: Okay, you can do `right` and `replace` in a `case`, added example